# SQL - Como descobrir qual a estação esta executando o Script e qual foi o script

Tags: sql

Atualmente preciso identificar qual usuário está rodando scripts no banco de dados e quais scripts são esses, visto que, alguns estão gerando lentidão na base.

O que consegui até o momento foi:

```sql
SELECT
    Processo      = spid
    ,Computador   = hostname
    ,Usuario      = loginame
    ,Status       = status
    ,BloqueadoPor = blocked
    ,TipoComando  = cmd
    ,Aplicativo   = program_name
FROM
    master..sysprocesses
WHERE
    status in ('runnable', 'suspended')
ORDER BY
    blocked desc, status, spid
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como identificar qual o script que esse usuário está executando?

Comment: a tabela `sysprocesses` tem a coluna "sql_handle" que te retorna o handle da query, onde é possível "descobrir" a query, mas isso depende da versão do banco de dados, em geral precisa fazer o `join` com a tabela `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`, mas no seu caso, não era mais fácil executar o profiler? ele mostra tudo isso já pronto, ainda pode filtrar e exportar, bem mais produtivo :)

Comment: Eu tentei usar o SQL_HANDLE, porem ele vem compactado o script. Nunca tentei usar o profiler